# Linq Expression Refactor Duplicate Code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, func, linq-expressions

I have some fairly duplicate code that is causing a little bit of a headache to re-factor.

**Expression< Func< TModel, DateTime>>**

```
public static HelperResult DataPickerFor<TModel>(
   HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, DateTime>> func, // DateTime
   IControlData data = null, Object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    data = data ?? new ControlData();
    data.ControlId = func.GetName();
    var dict = AddValueBinding(func, data, htmlAttributes);
    var label = html.LabelFor(func);
    var scriptResult = DateChangeEvent(data);
    var changeEvent = data.ControlId + "ChangeEvent"; 
    var input = html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(func).Format(
           Constants.Format.Date)
        .Events(e => e.Change(changeEvent)).HtmlAttributes(dict)
        .ParseFormats(new[] { Constants.Format.Date });
    return FormFieldTemplate(label, input, "date", scriptResult);
}
```

**Expression< Func< TModel,DateTime?>>**

```
public static HelperResult DataPickerFor<TModel>(
   HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, DateTime?>> func, // DateTime?
   IControlData data = null, Object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    data = data ?? new ControlData();
    data.ControlId = func.GetName();
    var dict = AddValueBinding(func, data, htmlAttributes);
    var label = html.LabelFor(func);
    var scriptResult = DateChangeEvent(data);
    var changeEvent = data.ControlId + "ChangeEvent"; 
    var input = html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(func)
        .Format(Constants.Format.Date)
        .Events(e => e.Change(changeEvent))
        .HtmlAttributes(dict).ParseFormats(new[] { Constants.Format.Date });
    return FormFieldTemplate(label, input, "date", scriptResult);
}
```

The only real difference is the DateTime? and DateTime. If I make the code generic using a 
 the DatePickerFor will break because it can nolonger infer the DateTime type.

Can I cast Func ?

Any other ideas would be great as well! There are a couple more permutations that I have not added so just living with the duplicate code is not idea.

**Signature for the DatePickerFor:**

```
public virtual DatePickerBuilder DatePickerFor(
    Expression<Func<TModel, DateTime?>> expression);
public virtual DatePickerBuilder DatePickerFor(
    Expression<Func<TModel, DateTime>> expression);
```

Comment: Your second snippet doesn't use `DateTime?`... did you mean to change the type of `func`?

Comment: I don't see any difference.

Comment: beyond compare says both are exactly same.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put the ? in the second one. I had changed the order of the two functions. I will fix a little more.

Comment: What is the signature of `DatePickerFor` method and `LabelFor` etc

Comment: Hi. Your `DateTime?`
 Version isn't using a nullable date time.

Comment: I have now supplied the DatePickerFor in the example.     public virtual DatePickerBuilder DatePickerFor(Expression<Func<TModel, DateTime?>> expression);
    public virtual DatePickerBuilder DatePickerFor(Expression<Func<TModel, DateTime>> expression);

Comment: I have also corrected the code to show the difference between the two ** DateTime ** and ** DateTime? **

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the function generic if you pass a delegate for the `DatePickerFor` function.

```
public static HelperResult DataPickerFor<TModel, TDateTime>(
   HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TDateTime>> func,
   Func<Expression<Func<TModel, TDateTime>>, HelperResult> f,
   IControlData data = null, Object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    data = data ?? new ControlData();
    data.ControlId = func.GetName();
    var dict = AddValueBinding(func, data, htmlAttributes);
    var label = html.LabelFor(func);
    var scriptResult = DateChangeEvent(data);
    var changeEvent = data.ControlId + "ChangeEvent"; 
    var input = f(func)
        .Format(Constants.Format.Date)
        .Events(e => e.Change(changeEvent))
        .HtmlAttributes(dict).ParseFormats(new[] { Constants.Format.Date });
    return FormFieldTemplate(label, input, "date", scriptResult);
}
```

Then your overloads become

```
public static HelperResult DataPickerFor<TModel>(
   HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, DateTime>> func, // DateTime?
   IControlData data = null, Object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    return DataPickerFor<TModel, DateTime>(html, func, f => html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(f), data, htmlAttributes);
}

public static HelperResult DataPickerFor<TModel>(
   HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, DateTime?>> func, // DateTime?
   IControlData data = null, Object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    return DataPickerFor<TModel, DateTime?>(html, func, f => html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(f), data, htmlAttributes);
}
```

You could probably simplify thus:

```
public static HelperResult DataPickerFor<TModel, TDateTime>(
   HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TDateTime>> func,
   HelperResult hr,
   IControlData data = null, Object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    data = data ?? new ControlData();
    data.ControlId = func.GetName();
    var dict = AddValueBinding(func, data, htmlAttributes);
    var label = html.LabelFor(func);
    var scriptResult = DateChangeEvent(data);
    var changeEvent = data.ControlId + "ChangeEvent"; 
    var input = hr
        .Format(Constants.Format.Date)
        .Events(e => e.Change(changeEvent))
        .HtmlAttributes(dict).ParseFormats(new[] { Constants.Format.Date });
    return FormFieldTemplate(label, input, "date", scriptResult);
}
```

and

```
public static HelperResult DataPickerFor<TModel>(
   HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, DateTime>> func, // DateTime?
   IControlData data = null, Object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    return DataPickerFor<TModel, DateTime>(html, func, html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(func), data, htmlAttributes);
}

public static HelperResult DataPickerFor<TModel>(
   HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, DateTime?>> func, // DateTime?
   IControlData data = null, Object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    return DataPickerFor<TModel, DateTime?>(html, func, html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(func), data, htmlAttributes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert Expression< Func< TModel, DateTime>> to Expression< Func< TModel, DateTime?>>, in that way you can eliminate code duplication. The conversion is implemented in my ConvertExpression method.

Of course we do not know the context of your problem entirely, but maybe you find this solution interesting - although this solution do not performs as well as the solution accepted.

```
    private void RunTest()
    {
        Expression<Func<string, DateTime?>> exp1 = p => new DateTime(2001, 1, 1);
        TestExpression(exp1, "exp1");

        Expression<Func<string, DateTime>> exp2 = p => new DateTime(2002, 2, 2);
        TestExpression(ConvertExpression(exp2), "exp2");
    }

    private void TestExpression<T>(Expression<Func<T, DateTime?>> expression, T parameter)
    {
        DateTime? dateTime = expression.Compile().Invoke(parameter);

        Console.WriteLine("DateTime to {0} is {1}", parameter, dateTime);
    }

    private Expression<Func<T, DateTime?>> ConvertExpression<T>(Expression<Func<T, DateTime>> expression)
    {
        var func = expression.Compile();
        Expression<Func<T, DateTime?>> convertedExpression = p => func(p);

        return convertedExpression;
    }
```

Output:

*DateTime to exp1 is 2001.01.01. 0:00:00*

*DateTime to exp2 is 2002.02.02. 0:00:00*

Comment: How does the conversion happen?

Comment: 1. I "extract" the original Func from the Expression what is achieved with the Compile method. As described in the documentation, this method "compiles the lambda expression described by the expression tree into executable code and produces a delegate that represents the lambda expression".
2. a new lambda expression is created, with the expected type: p => func(p). This lambda expression can be considered as a wrapper around the original lambda expression.
3. I create the Expression:  Expression< Func< TModel, DateTime?>> convertedExpression = p => func(p).

Comment: This raises a compile time error Expression<Func<TModel,Nullable<DateTime>>> is not assignable to Expression<Func<TModel,DateTime?>>.

Comment: This type of compile-time error is not possible. DateTime? is a "magic" only what is translated to Nullable<DateTime> by the C# compiler (check the IL with ildasm.exe). Be sure, Expression<Func<TModel,Nullable<DateTime>>> is assignable to Expression<Func<TModel,DateTime?>> and vice versa. Of course, I tested it on different framework versions, too.